# Expo router with authentication conditional rendering

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I use Expo router and am having trouble creating protected routes when working with authentication. I have a provider and global state for the current user logged in, which is working fine.

When I log in, i use `router.replace("/")` which takes me to the correct screen (profile).
If I sign out from the profile screen (i.e. setting the global user state to `null` nothing happens. It doesn't rerender, and allows the user to still see the protected route.

If I `console.log` the user object it says `null`.

**Video showing me signing in then signing out, without any rerender**

[image]

See file structure and return statements below.

```
- app (root folder)
- (app)
  - _layout.tsx
  - (tabs)
     - _layout.tsx
     - chat.tsx
     - profile.tsx

- login.tsx
- signup.tsx
- _layout.tsx
```

Inside `/_layout.tsx` (root) i have the following, where I declare all my Screens and provide the global state of the current user:

```
  <FirebaseAuthProvider>
        <Stack>
          <Stack.Screen name='login'/>
          <Stack.Screen name="signup"/>
          <Stack.Screen name="(app)"/>
        </Stack>
    </FirebaseAuthProvider>
```

Inside `(app)/_layout.tsx` have the following, where I conditionally redirect if the user is not logged in:

```
if(auth.isLoading){
    return <Text>Laddar</Text>
  }

  if(auth.user)
  {
  return <Redirect href="/login"/>
  }

  return (
    
      <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} /> 
      </Stack>
    
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with my `isLoading`, which did not update the state correctly. Once I fixed that, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different options to have the profile recognize that there isn’t a user. You can simply call router.replace(‘/login’) in the logout function. You could create an AuthProvider that runs this useEffect when the user changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
 
 if (!user) router.replace(“/login”)

}, [user])
```

Or you could put this useEffect in your profile screen and it should work.